# Best coding (layout) practice for the "main() class" file?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, methodology

Currently, my "main() class" file looks a bit like the following code.  Rather than clutter up this example code with //comments for discussion, I have simply labelled four code lines with numbers (1 to 4), and these numbers refer to questions that appear after the code.  Thank you.

```
// package myPackage;  // **1**

import myOtherPackage.*;

class mainProject{  // **2**

    // **3**
    private int myVar;

    mainProject(){
        myVar = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        // Keep main() looking fairly simple?
        // Perhaps just have some "essentials" here, such as error handling?

        new mainProject().start();  // **4**
    }

    private void start(){
        // The project gets going here..
    }
}
```

**1**  Unlike other class files in my project, I have not assigned a package name for my "main() class" file.  Is this a bad design choice?

**2**  Is there a good naming convention for the "main class"?  Is it helpful to incorporate the word "main" in to this class name?  Would something roughly like "mainProject" be a good idea?

**3**  Various coding constructs can appear inside the main class file.  For example, local variables, constructors, the main() method, and local methods.  Do they have a "best order" in which they appear in this file?

**4**  Is it worthwhile to keep the main() method looking fairly "lean and simple"?  In this example, I have just called a local private method called start(), which is intended to get the project started.

Comment: All classes should be in packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here is how I do it in my professional projects.

For 1. every class should have a package. Main or no main makes no difference. Package is the way java organizes your classes at runtime in form of namespaces. So if you stop giving packages then you may end up with two class files with same name in the same folder or jar and when that happens, JVM picks the first class it finds by the name on the classpath. That may not exactly be the one you want.

For 2. main (specially`public static void main(String[] args)` is a specific and standard signature that Java needs. Any runnable program, a program that produces an output and can be executed needs a main method with this signature. I will try to explain the signature and that maybe will help you understand why it's like that.

It's public because you want the JVM runtime code to execute the method. Using `private` or `protected` won't allow the JVM code to see your method.

It's static because without `static` the JVM code would need an instance of your class to actually access the method. Remember that static methods and fields can be accessed by just using the class name. However non static members need a valid live object to reach them.

It's void because main does not return anything to its caller. It's like any method having a void return type.

And it's called `main` because the Java creators thought to give it that name. JVM runtime code which executes this method needs to know about the name of your method which will kick off the execution. Now, if I name it anything then it's impossible for the JVM code to make a wild guess. So name standardization called for a standard name and Java creators stuck to `main`.

`String[]` is actually a string array containing the command line arguments that you pass to your program. `args` is the name of the argument and ironically this is the only thing that you can change to any name you want.

For naming the main class, I usually prefer the names like MyProjectLauncher or MyProjectBootstrap where myProject is the name of your project like tomcat or bigben or anything you like.

For 3. standard convention is:

```
public class MyClass{

    //private members

    //protected members

    //constructors

    //private methods

    //protected methods

    //public methods

    //hashcode and equals

    //toString overrides
}
```

You can pick what you need and drop what you need. Public methods also include the getters and setter for your variables if you use them.

For 4. When designing classes you need to keep in mind scalability and manageability of code. It's very common to have a `main` class and a few classes at start of the project and then when they grow into oversized kangaroos of thousands of lines then refactor code to adjust it. What you should do is create classes based on functionality, service helpers or actions. Keep `main` separate  in a different class. Just use `main` to initialize a few things, parse command line options and delegate to start or initialize method which does the remaining things to kick off your program.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Andrei...my english a bit rusty.

Comment: The edited summary description says "fixed spelling", but unfortunately it contains two spelling errors.  (Should be aligned and formatted.)

Answer (score 1):

1 yes you should always use packages. But dont use camelcase in them... So myotherpackage rather than myOtherpackage.

2 yes, it is good convention to incorporate the word main, e.g. MyApplicationMain. Remember class names start with a caps letter.

3 yes, the common order would be statics, members, constructors, methods, much like you have already

4 yes! This enables better testing and you should not use a static context for any longer than you need to.

If you add a package and take on board my tips for caps letters, i think what you have above is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually, it is good to define your own packages in order to avoid naming clashes with any other classes on your classpath. This also applies to the main class. Imagine what would happen if somewhere else in your dependencies there is a class whose creator used the same approach of leaving it in the default package. So yes, put iinto a package.
2. The naming is left at your latitude, but Java coding conventions definitely urge you to capitalize the name of the class. So, `Main` or `MainProject` or `EntryPoint` would be better choices.
3. I think you refer to fields and methods as members of the class. Please note that local variables and local methods have a totally different meaning (they're not members of the class itself). The usual ordering is static fields, instance fields, static methods constructors, instance methods. I don't think there is a strong convention, but these are the habits.
4. It is worthwhile keeping **any** method clean and simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

- ALWAYS use a `package`. No matter what. This is your namespace!
- Don't use `camelCase` in your package names.
- Avoid to import whole `packages.*`, better import a single `package.Clazz`.
- Class names should ALWAYS be `UpperCaseAndCamelCase`.
- Leave a space between the class or method name and the opening braket `{`, it improves readability.

The rest seems to be ok. It is more or less a matter of pragmatism. Your code has to fulfill the purpose it was written for and also needs to be testable and readable (by others).

All these criteria will form a ruleset for you or your team.

Answer (score 1):

1. What if someone else has a main class with the same name? Its better to place it in a package for all but the simplest test programs.
2. Incorporating "Main" in the class name is a good idea because it quickly tells the reader the purpose of the class, but "mainClass" should be "MainClass" according to [java language conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)
3. [The usual order is variables, constructors, and methods in whatever order is reasonable](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#1852)
4. Yes, keep the main method small and easily readable. The logic in it should mostly just be related to parameters passed to the program, and even that should be factored out when it gets to be too large.

Answer (score 1):

1 packages should definitely be used. It is better for maintenance purposes, if your project gets larger with time then there could be exact same syntax for main used. the package name should be meaningful as well and provide concise containment for relevant functionality classes.

2 yes, it is good to include the word main in the class name and should start with capital letter.

3 commonly the order is  variables, constructors, methods.

4 keep the main concise and simple. the lesser code it has the better as you already have done.